# How to differentiate two different node creation/edit pages

Tags: 8, nodes

I have 2 views, each one with a type of node (Products and Users). I want to add a unique class in each node create/edit pages, but i can't find any difference between the two, the only way i found is with the title of the page but that is not a good solution, because if the title changes it will stop working.

***I'm using the preprocess_html hook***

I tried with the route of the two pages but it's the same.

```
$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
/* Output:
/* Products edit page -> $route = entity.node.edit_form
/* Users edit page -> $route = entity.node.edit_form
/* 
/* In the node creation pages it's the same too
*/
```

Is there any way to find a difference in code from two node creation/edit pages?

This is the code i used to add classes to the same pages but now i need to add more specific classes like ***users_creation_page*** and ***products_creation_pages***

```
$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

  //Adding unique class to creation, edit and delete pages
  if (str_contains($route, 'add') || str_contains($route, 'create')) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'action-nodes-page';
  }
  elseif (str_contains($route, 'edit')) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'action-nodes-page';
  }
  elseif (str_contains($route, 'delete')) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-delete-page';
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to preprocess node type specific?

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

// #### implements hook_preprocess_html() ####

function yourmodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

switch ( $variables['node']->getType() ) {

// ## node-type: products ##
case 'products':

  ...

break;

// ## node-type: users ##
case 'users':

  ...

break;

default:

  ...

}

}
```

Comment: Yup, sorry i didn't know exactly how to properly formulate the question but this solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: @Gabri If this solved the issue, please use the checkbox by the votes for the question to mark this answer as accepted.